# Fans not running when 2018 MBP is in Bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, catalina

I have Windows 10 installed on a Bootcamp partition of my 2018 MacBook Pro. When booted in macOS, the fans run fine (i.e. whenever the computer is in high load and hot).

But when I'm in Windows, the fans are completely quiet and I cannot feel any airflow from behind the machine. When I switch into macOS and check the CPU temperature using Macs Fan Control, it always reads high-90s and starts gunning the fans until it cools down, leading me to think that the CPU is throttling itself properly.

I've tried resetting the SMC following [the instructions here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295#t2), doing both the normal steps and the "If that doesn't resolve the issue" steps, but to no avail. Has anyone else had this problem, and has anything worked for you to get the fans to actually run in Windows?

Comment: Did you try installing Macs Fan Control Windows version?  It will show you the temps and fan speeds while in Windows.

Comment: Yeah; unfortunately, Macs Fan Control does not work in Bootcamp for computers with the T2 chip, which my 2018 MBP has. (https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control/supported-models)